# Table of Contents – How to display some chapter entries (namely the frontmatter and appendices) in italics

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft

For making font changes for all chapter, I use the following command from the `tocloft` package: `\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\normalfont\hfill}`.

However, for this use case, I need the main chapter entries to be in normal font and the front matter and appendix entries to be in italics. An example is the following:

[image]

Comment: Welcome, you haven't given any clue what's going on. The screenshot you uploaded shows a table of contents far from the default look. Are you using a special documentclass? Where can we get it? Can you provide a minimal working example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to insert the font changing commands into the ToC by using the standard `\addtocontents` macro. For example

```
\documentclass{book} % No idea what your class is
\usepackage{tocloft}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\protect\itshape}}
\chapter{Preface}
\chapter{Acknowledgements}

\mainmatter
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\protect\normalfont}}
\chapter{First}
\chapter{Second}

\backmatter
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\protect\itshape}}
\chapter{Notes}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\usepackage{tocloft}` changes the formatting of the whole toc.

Comment: @AdilAliyev No it does not. It only changes what you tell it to change.